# Fullcalendar.io - how to see all options, in docs?

Tags: fullcalendar, documentation

I'm struggling with the documentation for https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc.  Specifically, how to see the various settings for a given option.

For example, with `eventTimeFormat`: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventTimeFormat

In some examples i've seen that I can set

```
hour: 'numeric',
```

or

```
hour: '2-digit',
```

but I can't find anywhere that says "The options for `hour` are '2-digit', 'numeric', 'foo', 'bar' etc", explaining what each one does.

In actual fact, what I want to do is to not show the time at all inside the event box itself, and save the space for the event title, but I feel like at least understanding how to get to the info myself in the docs would be the first step.  Are these options actually explained anywhere?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-formatting . It's already linked from the eventTimeFormat page you mentioned above, and from the docs home page.

Comment: But ... _what I want to do is to not show the time at all inside the event_. ... in that case forget about formatting and see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/displayEventTime

Comment: @ADyson ah, thanks, I must have just been a bit blind.